# Azure Data Factory Remove Empty Child Directory

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

In the following file structure

container/Directory/Sub-Directory

I wish to delete Sub-Directory --because at this point in my process it is empty.

Note: I am using the term 'Directory' as opposed to folder as this structure was added using 'Add Directory' -- I'm not sure if this is just a semantic difference directory/folder or is significant.

On invoking a delete shape using a dataset where the

Container, Directory and Sub-Directory are passed as parameters.

Within the delete shape setting

I am substituting within the boxes as follows.

|$Container/@concat( $Directory,'/', $Sub-Directory ) /     -- Filename is left blank.

On invoking the shape the following error occurs.

Failed to execute delete activity with data source
'AzureBlobStorage' and error
'The required Blob is missing.

Folder path: Container/Directory/Sub-Directory/.'.
For details, please reference log file here:

It appears to be looking for a file to delete?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot create an empty directory in Azure Blob Storage account. It's possible only in ADLS GEN2. You mentioned that the requirement is to delete the already existing empty folder in the storage account. So, your storage account must be ADLS GEN2.

In ADF, we can create two linked service for an ADLS storage account i.e, **Azure Blob Storage** and **Azure Data Lake Storage**.

I tried with **Azure Blob Storage** linked service and got same error.

[image]

> It appears to be looking for a file to delete?

No. **AFAIK**, Using Blob storage linked service might be the reason for this error as you can see, for the empty folder(directory) `subfolder3` it gave me same error when I browse through the files.

[image]

When I use the same Delete activity with **Azure Data Lake Storage** linked service, I am able to delete the empty folder.

[image]

So, you can try the Azure Data Lake Storage as a workaround for it.